# Join 2 data frames based on column

Tags: r, dataframe

This is a really simple question. I would like to join 2 data.frames based on columns. Please see below df1 sample structure:

```
 t1 t2 t3
     0  0  0
     1  1  1
     1  1  1
     1  1  1
```

Df2 has the different column number the same number of rows:

```
 t1 t2 t3 t4
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0
```

Output:

```
 t1 t2 t3 t4
 0  0  0  0
 1  1  1  0
 1  1  1  0
 1  1  1  0
```

Sample data:

```
df1<-structure(list( t1=c(0,1,1,1), t2=c(0,1,1,1),t3 = c(0,1,1,1)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Original data sample the first 2 rows from my original data

```
df1

    structure(list(X1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), Duration = c(10, 
    20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100), `00:00` = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `00:10` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
        `00:20` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `00:40` = c(2, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `00:50` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        1, 0, 0, 0), `01:00` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `01:20` = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), `01:30` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), `01:40` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `03:40` = c(2, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `04:00` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), `04:10` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `04:20` = c(1, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `10:30` = c(2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), `11:20` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `11:50` = c(2, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `12:00` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), `12:10` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `12:20` = c(0, 
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `12:30` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), `12:40` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `12:50` = c(1, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `13:10` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), `13:30` = c(2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `13:50` = c(0, 
        1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `14:00` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), `14:10` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `14:20` = c(1, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `14:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), `14:40` = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `14:50` = c(2, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `15:00` = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), `15:10` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `15:20` = c(0, 
        1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `15:30` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), `15:50` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `16:00` = c(1, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `16:10` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), `16:30` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `16:50` = c(1, 
        0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `17:00` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), `17:10` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `17:20` = c(0, 
        0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `17:30` = c(0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), `17:50` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `18:00` = c(0, 
        0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), `18:10` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), `18:30` = c(2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `18:40` = c(1, 
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `18:50` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), `19:00` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `19:10` = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `19:20` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), `19:30` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `19:40` = c(1, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), `19:50` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), `20:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `20:10` = c(1, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `20:20` = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 2, 0), `20:40` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), `20:50` = c(4, 
        0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `21:00` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), `21:10` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `21:20` = c(2, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `21:30` = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), `21:40` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `22:00` = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `22:10` = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 1, 0, 0), `22:20` = c(0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `22:40` = c(1, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `22:50` = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
        0, 1, 0, 0), `23:00` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), `23:10` = c(1, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `23:20` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0), `23:30` = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `23:40` = c(0, 
        0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `23:50` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))

    df2
```

structure(list(Duration = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `04:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `04:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `04:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `04:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `04:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `04:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `05:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `05:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `05:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `05:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `05:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `05:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `06:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `06:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `06:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `06:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `06:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `06:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `07:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `07:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `07:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `07:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `07:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `07:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `08:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `08:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `08:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `08:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `08:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `08:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `09:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `09:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `09:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `09:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `09:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `09:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `10:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `10:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `10:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `10:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `10:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `10:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `11:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `11:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `11:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `11:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `11:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `11:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `12:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `12:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `12:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `12:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `12:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `12:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `13:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `13:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `13:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `13:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `13:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `13:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `14:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `14:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `14:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `14:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `14:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `14:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `15:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `15:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `15:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `15:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `15:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `15:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `16:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `16:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `16:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `16:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `16:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `16:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `17:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `17:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `17:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `17:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `17:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `17:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `18:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `18:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `18:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `18:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `18:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `18:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `19:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `19:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `19:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `19:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `19:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `19:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `20:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `20:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `20:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `20:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `20:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `20:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `21:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `21:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `21:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `21:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `21:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `21:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `22:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `22:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `22:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `22:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `22:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `22:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `23:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `23:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `23:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `23:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `23:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `23:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `00:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `00:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `00:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `00:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `00:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `00:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `01:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `01:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `01:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `01:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `01:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `01:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `02:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `02:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `02:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `02:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `02:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `02:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `03:00` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `03:10` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `03:20` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `03:30` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), `03:40` = c(NA_character_,
NA_character_), `03:50` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA,
-2L), class

= c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could just use assignment based on the column names in `base R`

```
df2[names(df1)] <- df1
df2
#  t1 t2 t3 t4
#1  0  0  0  0
#2  1  1  1  0
#3  1  1  1  0
#4  1  1  1  0
```

If there are column names in 'df1' that are not in 'df2'

```
nm1 <- intersect(names(df1), names(df2))
df2[nm1] <- df1[nm1]
```

Comment: thanks, the code works but when I am using with my data I receive the following error Error: Can't recycle input of size 77 to size 144.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred

Comment: @user11418708 i assume that you have column names that are in 'df1' not in 'df2'.  I updated the post.  Perhaps that helps

Comment: truly many thanks but still I receive the following errors Error: Assigned data `df1[nm1]` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 0 rows.
x Element 1 of assigned data has 18 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.

Comment: @user11418708 can you update the post with a small example that shows the error i.e. `dput` of the example so that the structure is known.  Here, I am assuming that your dataset have common column names.  Can you check if there is any difference in names

Comment: @user11418708 thanks, I think your new dataset have different number of rows.  I was thinking that both the datasets have the same number of rows

Comment: @user11418708 i.e. df1 shows 10 rows and df2 with 2 rows.  Where does the value of df1 goes into df2 row

Comment: @user11418708 suppose you want the first two rows of 'df1' to fill the two rows in 'df2' then `df2[nm1] <- df1[1:2, nm1]` works, otherwise, there is a dimension mismatch.  From the examples, I didn't find any other pattern.  Can you please help me in understanding those

Comment: thanks basically df2 is am empty data  frame with 144 columns, but the column names of df1 and df2 are identical. So, for example, 3 columns from df1 match 3 columns of df2. So I would like to have the 3 columns  from df1 in df2  an the other 141 columns with zeros

Comment: @user11418708 i assume that 'df2' have the same number of rows as 'df1'.  In that case, it should work because I am able to get it work with the new data (with same number of rows)

Comment: @user11418708 Based on the column names, there are 78 matches `length(intersect(names(df1), names(df2)))
[1] 78`

Answer (score 1):

In this case `bind_cols()` can be a good choice.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- structure(list( t1=c(0,1,1,1), t2=c(0,1,1,1),t3 = c(0,1,1,1)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list( t1=c(0,0,0,0), t2=c(0,0,0,0),t3 = c(0,0,0,0), t4 = c(0,0,0,0)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

add <- df2 %>%
  select(-colnames(df1))

df1 %>%
  bind_cols(add)

#   t1 t2 t3 t4
# 1  0  0  0  0
# 2  1  1  1  0
# 3  1  1  1  0
# 4  1  1  1  0
```